# I am using tiles but the css file of baselayout wont be applied on all pages

Tags: css, jsp, struts2, tiles

the problem is that I have a css file that is pointed from my baselayout.jsp file as following, when I am in index.php it applies the css but when I move to Profile/view.jsp it does not.

when I look at the source I noticed it is looking the css file in Profile/stylesheets/Base.css rather than myproject/stylesheets/Base.css, how to point to it in a way that works on all pages.

```
   <link href="<s:url value="/stylesheets/mycss.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a breeze, just change the address to solid address, as following

```
   http://www.example.com/myPreoject/stylesheets/Base.css
```